# Apply a Qt layout to a randomly placed widgets UI

Tags: qt, layout

In my Qt 5.10.0 project under CentOS 7, I have a UI file that contains a picture of a device, and on the picture are some labels and buttons randomly placed on the picture (randomly here means no forms of rows or columns). I added a scroll area and then added everything inside it. When I apply any type of layout so that the scroll area works, the widgets get misplaced in a crazy way.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPbkJt2CYvk) for example, the scroll area's layout works because the widgets are placed in a row fashion and you can add as many rows as you want. I found several other tutorials with similar design.

Since the layout is necessary for the scroll area to work, I had several ideas in mind:

1. Writing a custom layout manager specific for this UI and then set the scroll area's layout to be an instance of it.
2. <strike>Try and re-design the UI and force the layout to be more organized. I tried this but the image breaks everything misplacing all widgets.</strike>
3. <strike>Grouping some widgets in horizontal layout for example and then grouping the layouts in a vertical one for example. But then again the image breaks everything.</strike>
4. I have another UI in which scroll area works but because the widget's layed-out in rows fashion then grouped in group-boxes which did not need extra steps.

What do you suggest for implementing a scroll area on such a UI?

P.S.: Sorry to not provide any code sample. All proprietary.

Comment: Actually, the layout is not necessary for the scroll area to work. QScrollArea is designed to show a small area of its client widget, viewport, which in turn is the owner of the layout. But it is possible to set viewport's dimensions and add children widgets directly to viewport.

Comment: @AlexanderZavertan Well I tried putting everything inside group box and put this group box inside a scroll area. It did not work until I set a layout to the group box.

Comment: Add new QScrollArea. Set it's property **widgetResizeable** to false. Set proper width and height for QScrollArea's child widget geometry. Now you have scrollable area with desired client area size.

Comment: Are you sure QGraphicsScene will not fit better in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a scroll area on Widget with 3 randomly-placed buttons inside it.

```
void setupUi(QWidget *Widget)
{
    scrollArea = new QScrollArea(Widget);
    scrollArea->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 200, 200));
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false); // Important! Without this, QScrollArea will try to shrink viewport widget.
    scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget();
    scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)); // Now scrollable area has size 1000x1000 px.
    pushButton = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    pushButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton"));
    pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(10, 70, 82, 23));
    pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    pushButton_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton_2"));
    pushButton_2->setGeometry(QRect(130, 110, 82, 23));
    pushButton_3 = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    pushButton_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton_3"));
    pushButton_3->setGeometry(QRect(70, 170, 82, 23));
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
} // setupUi
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems not to work. When I resize I don't get a scroll bar.

Comment: @3bdalla, have you tried to force scrollbars with`scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn); scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);` ?

Comment: Since I am using Qt creator, It seems that my problem was with the widget resizable property, and sometimes when I add the scroll area, I forgot to set it as a central widget. Nevertheless it works perfectly. Thanks!